# Keyboard not responding after resuming from suspend

Tags: keyboard, suspend, lubuntu

A fresh install of Lubuntu 16.04 (not dual, just Linux) on a HP EliteBook Folio G1 (with touchpad screen) seems to perform well, except for the fact that after resuming from the suspend state, the keyboard is unresponsive, and have to be restarted to continue operating.

Edit:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash atkbd.reset"
```

`update-grub` and `reboot` already tried, with no result. [credit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38797/keyboard-not-working-after-suspend-to-ram-sleep)

Comment: Does your notebook have FN function key?
There is a option on every notebook for keyboard/touchpad disable/enable i think maybe that can help u.

Comment: Have tried all that, pressing all combinations. No response. After some time it goes blank again, as if nothing would have been pressed, and it's only the touchpad that awakes the screen again.

Comment: Can you give me output of dmesg command

Comment: @Luka, please, help: how can I do that? the output is too big to be included in the question body, but too small to be posted to textuploader.com, any idea?

Comment: Use pastebin.com

Comment: @Luka here it is: http://pastebin.com/XznU0c3n

Comment: @luka may be this is not what you need, as I can't suspend and get back to my session (since I can't type the pw), let me change this and report again...

Comment: Ok... try this

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all 

or

sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all

Comment: @luka I already tried that, nothing changed.  It said that no new drivers were installed or upgraded.

Comment: Did u tried with reinstall parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52658/discussion-between-nightcod3r-and-luka).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0Ebczp1j